# Should I return ValueTask if I still use TaskCompletionSource to implement asynchrony?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library, valuetask

Is there still a benefit in returning `ValueTask` if I use `TaskCompletionSource` to implement actual asynchrony?

As I understand it, the purpose of `ValueTask` is to reduce allocations, but allocations are still there when awaiting `TaskCompletionSource.Task`. Here is a simple example to illustrate the question:

```
async ValueTask DispatcherTimerDelayAsync(TimeSpan delay) 
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = delay;
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => tcs.SetResult(true);
    timer.Start();
    try
    {
        await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Should I rather be returning `Task` (versus `ValueTask`) from `DispatcherTimerDelayAsync`, which itself is always expected to be asynchronous?

Comment: Seems to me your method can be simplified to `await Task.Delay(delay);`. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @Tanveer remove the `async` and just `return Task.Delay(delay);`: even fewer allocs!

Comment: Related reading: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html

Comment: @TanveerBadar, indeed it can, it's a made-up example just to show what I meant.

Comment: I should have mentioned that, in the real life it is a custom I/O controller which I access via interop and a vendor-provided C++ Win32 DLL, but it still comes down to turning callbacks into Tasks, and I use `TaskCompletionSource` for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are pros and cons of each. In the "pro" column:

1. *When returning a result synchronously* (i.e. `Task<T>`), using `ValueTask<T>` avoids an allocation of the task - however, this **doesn't apply** for "void" (i.e. non-generic `Task`), since you can just return `Task.CompletedTask`
2. When you are issuing multiple sequential awaitables, you can use a single "value task source" with sequential tokens to reduce allocations

(a special-case of "2" might be amortization via tools like `PooledAwait`)

It doesn't *feel* like either of those apply here, but: if in doubt, remember that it is allocation-free to return a `Task` *as* a `ValueTask` (`return new ValueTask(task);`), which would allow you to consider changing the implementation to an allocation-free one later without breaking the signature. You still pay for the original `Task` etc of course - but exposing them *as `ValueTask`* doesn't add any extra.

In all honesty, I'm not sure I'd worry too much about this in this case, since a delay is ways going to be allocatey.

Comment: Thanks, this helps! A great blog post, too! In the real life it is a custom I/O controller which I access via interop and a vendor-provided C++ Win32 DLL, but it still comes down to turning callbacks into Tasks, and I use `TaskCompletionSource` for that.

Comment: Would that be a good idea to implement my own cache of IValueTaskSource-based tasks, using something like `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`?

Comment: @avo if we're talking about sequential (rather than overlapping) operations, and if reducing allocations *is key* (frankly, it often isn't), then yes: that could definitely help. But a lot of times you don't even need a cache as such - if you can simple keep and a the `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore` as a field on the instance.

Comment: I've just gone through your [`PooledAwait`](https://mgravell.github.io/PooledAwait/) and `PooledValueTaskSource` seems to be exactly what I should be looking for. Great work, thank you. I hope TPL will provide something like this in .NET 5 or later.

Comment: Not in v5, the bits were merged few months ago I believe but the feature is off through a flag in v5 timeline from what I understand.

Comment: @MarcGravell Would an implementation of request response based protocol fit case number 2? For example a protocol that supports windowing, (sending multiple requests before receiving a response, using sequence numbers to match req to resp).

Comment: @uriDium it could do, depending on context; you can only have one outstanding result per ivaluetasksource, normally, though - so you might need to be careful if you have overlapped requests - you'd need to abstract the reuse carefully

Comment: Yes the protocol does support overlapped requests. I was thinking of maintaining a dictionary of ValueTask keyed on the request's sequence number. I did this easily with TaskCompletionSource quite easily but want to keep down the pressure on the GC. It is quite a high throughput service, but it is still an over optimization but I was doing it for my own interest and understanding.

Comment: @uriDium yes, it absolutely can be done; it needs to be done carefully and mindfully; as an example, "PooledAwait" uses a separate pool of reusable IVTS, which means that ordering (overlapped, etc) isn't an issue: it simply tries to take something from the pool, and allocates if it can't - and puts things back into the pool when the result is fetched.

Answer (score 5):

`ValueTask` is a struct, whereas `Task` is a class that's why it might reduce the allocations. (`struct`s are allocated most of the time on the stack, so they will vanish automatically when the method exits (exiting the strackframe). `class`es are allocated mostly on the heap, where a GC **Collect** or **Sweep** have to be performed to gather unreachable objects. So, if you can allocate on a stack then your heap memory allocation is not growing (because of this object) that's why the GC is not triggered.

The main benefit of `ValueTask` can be seen when your code executes mainly synchronously. It means that if the expected value is already present then there is no need to create a promise (`TaskCompletionSource`), which will be fulfilled in the future.

You also don't need to worry about allocation in case of `Task<bool>` because in both cases the corresponding Task objects are cached by the runtime itself. The same applies for `Task<int>` but only for numbers between -1 and 9. [Reference](https://books.google.hu/books?id=pIx5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA477&lpg=PA477&dq=task%3Cint%3E%20caching&source=bl&ots=r1JAtelvVq&sig=ACfU3U0VHzC-kAzFNNBCbN5GhiZ-Fhwn5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn1IiKnb3qAhXJpIsKHYe9CXwQ6AEwAXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

So in short, you should use `Task` in this case instead of `ValueTask`.

Comment: This is a great answer, i was so sceptical when i started to read this, but you surprised me. The only thing i would add is, unless your benchmarks and profiling tells you that you are going to benefit from the use of a ValueTask on your hot paths and that the down stream code can abide by its requirements, then you should just use a regular task

Comment: @TheGeneral First all of thanks. You are absolutely right with the measurement suggestions. Measure before make any long lasting decision.

Comment: @TheGeneral the "something accessed in an async way multiple times but sequentially" scenario is also a very compelling candidate for `ValueTask[<T>]` - via the "source+token" approach

Comment: @MarcGravell compelling indeed. 3 things things to live by, Be good to your mother, allocations and thread pool. And always ask yourself "*what would MarcGravell do*" :P

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm not sure I'd trust that idiot, but I think he'd [Prefer ValueTask to Task, always](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html)

Comment: @MarcGravell nice find! He has a some good things to say, and well read ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell, maybe not always but mostly? :) I mean, there could be twisted cases like WhenAll/WhenAny were you'd still want to have a `Task`? Or are you saying that the user of the API should be responsible for that and use ValueTask.AsTask?

Comment: *"The same applies for `Task<int>` but only for numbers between 0 and 10."* <== is this documented, or you know it by studying the source code?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I read that once in the Pro .NET Memory Management book on page [477](https://books.google.hu/books?id=pIx5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA477&lpg=PA477&dq=task%3Cint%3E+caching&source=bl&ots=r1JAtelvVq&sig=ACfU3U0VHzC-kAzFNNBCbN5GhiZ-Fhwn5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn1IiKnb3qAhXJpIsKHYe9CXwQ6AEwAXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). I've edited the post because I remembered to a wrong range.

Comment: @avo indeed, one should *never ever* talk in absolutes :)

Comment: Thanks Peter for the link! I asked because in a video titled [Tip 5: Async libraries APIs should be chunky](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Async-libraries-APIs-should-be-chunky), Lucian Wischik claimed that .NET Framework preallocates tasks for the values 0 and 1. He says so at around 8:00. It is a relatively old video (2014), so things may have changed in between. The book you are referring is newer. :-)